# Where do I set anonymous checkout without users hit the login page?

Tags: 7, commerce, users

After adding an item to the Drupal Commerce cart, I hit the cart review page. Then I click on checkout and I'm hit with the login page, is there a setting where users don't have to login and just checkout anonymously. And if they already have an account on the site their order would be added to their account in reference to their email.

Comment: I would make note to the users who accepted the suggested edit that the OP clearly stated in a comment for the accepted answer they aren't using Commerce Kickstart, so adding a sentence saying they are using Commerce Kickstart is contrary to what the OP is saying. Let's not put words in the OP's mouth.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You aren't just using Drupal Commerce, are you? It sounds like you're using Commerce Kickstart or Drupal Commerce with the [Commerce Checkout Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect) module enabled. That's what's responsible for the behavior you're describing. Just disable it and enable the "Access checkout" permission that David Thomas pointed to.

Comment: ok ill make sure i mention if im using kickstart or not. actually im not using kickstart. I installed core Commerce and building it up from scratch without all the bloat. I want to try to do everything within core Commerce if possible so upgrading won't be an issue if I start using other modules that don't get updated. thanks! I'm posting alot of Commerce stuff because I want to be able to document all the newbie questions that others would run into when building up Commerce from scratch without Kickstart.

Answer (score 9):

You may need to check the permission, under `Admin > People > Permissions : "Access checkout"` for anonymous users.

If the user does log in, their anonymous order will be added to their authenticated user cart.